# How do I configure the settings of my Facebook app?

Tags: facebook, canvas

I want to be able to access my app through facebook canvas. So I set the settings configuration as I saw in many tutorials.

- Canvas URL
- Secure Canvas URL
- Site URL

All the same https://mysite.com/ Also set the Namesapace (myapp_canvas), Display Name (mayapp name) and App Domain (mysite).

When I try to enter the app through canvas (https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_canvas) I get the following error:

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Usually that error occurs because the request domain does not match up with `mysite.com`.

If you are in development, try editing your `/etc/hosts` (or `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` if on Windows) file to have this line.

```
127.0.0.1 local.mysite.com
```

And if you are making requests to Facebook remotely, make sure the domain ends with `mysite.com`; ex. `app.mysite.com`, `dev.mysite.com`, etc.